# Unit Test with Mocha inside jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, mocha.js

I have a piece of code in JS which is using jQuery:

```
$() => {
function display(text) {
        infoNotifier.displayInfo({ message: text });
      }
}
```

infoNotifier is reference to another module.
How can I unit test the display function? This function is also used in same file in the same jQuery executing.

Comment: nodejs in the same file as jquery ? sonething wrong here. Nodejs is server side and jquery client side

Comment: sorry this is the client side code. I will fix the error

Comment: Is this a UI behavior? I suppose you could query the DOM for the kind of element that gets created and its content but it will not be a unit test.